# Polymorphism Code Java

Tags: java, polymorphism

I have some code from my teacher that involves polymorphism. We are asked what the output will be if you call a particular method. I didn't know really what to do, so I ran the code through eclipse, and found my answers like that. However, we do have a test coming up and I don't know what I should do (thinking-wise) if a similar question is given.

Here is the code:

```
public class Harry {
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("harry 1");
    }

    public void method2() {
        method1();
        System.out.println("harry 2");
    }
}

public class Larry extends Harry {
    public void method1() {
        System.out.println("larry 1");
        super.method1();
    }
}

public class Mary extends Larry {
    public void method2() {
        System.out.println("mary 2");
    }

    public void method3() {
        super.method1();
        System.out.println("mary 3");
    }
}

public class Jerry extends Mary {
    public void method2() {
        super.method2();
        System.out.println("jerry 2");
    } 
}

Harry var1 = new Harry();
Harry var2 = new Larry();
Larry var3 = new Jerry();
Mary var4 = new Mary();
Mary var5 = new Jerry();
Object var6 = new Larry();
```

I know that if `var2.method2()` was called it would output:

```
larry 1
harry 1
harry 2
```

but I'm not sure why. Wouldn't it only output

```
harry 1
harry 2
```

?

Thanks for your time and any answers.

Comment: When `method1();` is called, even inside `Harry::method2()`, the current instance is `Larry`, so `Larry::method1()` will be called. That's how polymorphism works.

Comment: @songyuanyao thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`var2.method2()`

`var2` *ISA* `Larry`, meaning it's an instance of the `Larry` object (from the right hand side variable declaration).

Follow the method calls from Larry and you'll get that first output

The first called method will be this, which goes to the `method1()` for `Larry` because the reasons above and `method1()` was overridden

```
public void method2() {
    method1();
    System.out.println("harry 2");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to play a little game: you're the computer. Now let's assume you know Java and understand inheritance, polimorphism, you just do step-by-step:

```
Harry var2 = new Larry();

var2.method2(); // Larry doesn't have it's own method2, so go to Harry.method2

Harry.method2: call method1() // method1 was overridden by Larry, so eventhough
// you're now in Harry, yo execute Larry.method1

  Larry.method1: print "larry 1"
  Larry.method1: call super.method1 // super is Harry

  Harry.method1: print "harry 1"
  Harry.method1: return to caller // Harry.method2

Harry.method2: print "harry 2"
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to understand this is to not pay attention to the reference type, but rather to what it is referencing.

If you see a statement like:

```
Harry var2 = new Larry();
```

Then just know that any method called with that object will first look in the class type which is referenced (`Larry`). If the method is not found there, only then will it look in the super class of the object, which in this case would be (`Harry`).

If the method call is still not found in Harry, it will keep traversing up the inheritance tree doing this search until it either finds the attribute needed or finally gets to the parent of all Java objects which is `Object`. If the method or attribute is not found, then this is an invalid operation and the compiler will complain and whine